# Access nested json with ng-repeat to build a table

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'd like to build a table that looks like that : [image: table]

I tried something in my dataset, but as datas are nested, I don't have any idea how I can display them with ng-repeat in my html.

wslists can is resultJ1,2,3, the numbers are numbers from listnqJ1 for day1, listnqJ2 for day 2 etc..
Also resultsJ1,2,3 and listnqJ1,2,3 are lists.

```js
table = [
  { day: " Day1" , webservices : [
                  {ws: resultsJ1, tnq : listnqJ1 }
                  ]
  },
  { day: " Day2", webservices : [
                  {ws :resultsJ2, tnq : listnqJ2 }
                  ]
  },
  { day: " Day3" , webservices : [
    {ws :resultsJ3, tnq : listnqJ3 }
    ]
}
  ]

$scope.listnqJ1 = tableau[0].webservices[0].tnq;
  $scope.listnqJ2 = tableau[1].webservices[0].tnq;
  $scope.listnqJ3 = tableau[2].webservices[0].tnq;

$scope.resultsJ1 = tableau[0].webservices[0].ws;
  $scope.resultsJ2 = tableau[1].webservices[0].ws;
  $scope.resultsJ3 = tableau[2].webservices[0].ws;
    

self.tableau = tableau
```

I found that in my html, it works for the resultsJ1,2,3 lists but I have a huge problem displaying the results under Day 1, 2 , 3 of listnqJ1,2,3.

```html
 <table cellpadding="20" rules="GROUPS" frame="BOX">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Web Service</th>
        <th style="width: 100px" ng-repeat="day in ctrl.tableau ">
          {{day.jour}}
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>
  <tr style="width: 100px" class="xl153" ng-repeat="ws in resultsJ1 track by $index">
    <td>{{ws}}</td>

    <td style="width: 100px" class="xl153" ng-repeat="day in ctrl.tableau" >
     
        <td
          style="width: 100px"
          class="xl153"
          ng-repeat="tnq in listnqJ1 track by $index"
        >
          {{tnq}}
        </td>
      </td>

  </tr>
  <tr  class="xl153" ng-repeat="ws in resultsJ2 track by $index">
    <td>{{ws}}</td>

</tbody>
  </table>
```

I'd like to display in column listnqJ1 under Day 1, listnqJ2, under day 2  etc..

here is a sample of the lists

in red **resultsJ1,2,3** and in blue **listnqJ1,2,3**

[image]

Comment: Two steps: 1. rearrange your data so it's an array of objects, where each object contains the data of a single row 2. the rest is easy

Comment: it’s a little fuzzy for me as I’m a beginner, could you please, show me what would  this array of objects look like ? @ChrisG

Comment: The first element of that array would look like this: `{ wslist: "sbe_global-service-requests-for-self-care", day1: 100, day2: 0, day3: 152 }`. Not in code of course, but if logged to the console. Like I said, you need to rearrange your data into the structure of a table, i.e. an array of objects that all have the same keys. What exactly is `resultsJ1` for instance?

Comment: To be clear: this question is not really about angular tables. It is primarily about rearranging data into a normalized format. Provide us with shortened example input data and we can help you get it into the required format.

Comment: okay I see, but in my case It is not possible to call each key like that because there are thousands of webservices and the same amount of numbers in listnq. resultsJ1 is the list of webservices for day 1 and listnqJ1 is a list of results (called tnq) for day 1 for the webservices of day 1. What I showed on the picture is just a tiny sample of the table.

Comment: You assume you have to write out each key manually but that's not necessary at all. You iterate over them and build the table from that.

Comment: I updated my post so you can see what resultsJ1 and listnqJ1 look like.

Comment: Also I know I can iterate over them, that is precisely what I've tried with ng-repeat but encountered issues. But in your example your wrote the key of the lists that's why I asked

Comment: That's the thing: you're iterating over them while building the table, but you have to iterate over them while building the *table data*. Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/6uf9h2tq/

Comment: Ok thank you for the example, I'm going to try this. Also I thought about doing a get value function $scope.getValue = function(jour, ws) {
    
       return tnq[jour,ws]
     
  }. The function displays in the right place as I wanted but it it doesn't return the numbers of the tnqlist. Do you think I should dig that idea?

Comment: `tnq[jour, ws]` won't work. `tnq` is an array, you cannot put multiple indexes inside the square brackets.

Comment: $scope.getValue = function(ws, wsIndex, jour, dayIndex) {
    
       return listnqJ1[ wsIndex +  dayIndex*(resultsJ1.length)]
     
  } this seems to work for the first list